# Filtering by date - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to filter by date so I can delete previous data with the same date and update it. I am having issues with this part of the code since it will not filter correctly if the date format varies between 03/07/18 and 03/07/2018.

How might I account for the difference in formatting, as the users may input the date in both ways? Thank you!

```
Sheet3.Select
dateToFind = Sheet8.Range("L6")
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
Selection.AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:=dateToFind

Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If lr > 1 Then
    Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: *the date format varies between 03/07/18 and 03/07/2018* - then start with fixing the data so that it's consistent?

Comment: The format should be irrelevant. If the data contains `Date` values and they're understood as such by Excel, you're working with `Date` values, not `String` values. What's the type of `dateToFind`? `String`? Is it declared? Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module and declare all your variables if it isn't.

Comment: I assume some of the entries are entered as text, and excel will not recognize it as a date value. Maybe select the entire column and format it as date. If that does not work, you can try selecting the entire column J, then go to Data=>and select "Text to Column", hit next a couple of times until you see a Date option, select the date option and finish, see if that did anything.

Comment: @Davesexcel that worked perfectly, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set format as universal set text to column as follows.

```
> Columns("K:K").Select 'reformat date to function in the rest of the
> macro
>     Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("k1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
>         TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
>         Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
>         :=Array(1, 3), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```